# iPad getting annoyed by upgrade requests

Tags: ipad, upgrade

I have an original iPad. I cannot upgrade it anymore because the newer OS's do not work with an original iPad.

Unfortunately, I get incessant upgrade notifications.

Is there any way to turn these off?

Comment: What iOS version are you running?

Comment: version 9.1 blah blah more text  blah blah

Comment: Please be specific.

Comment: Are you using the original iPad? The original iPad only supports till iOS 5.1.1

Comment: Hmm, well 9.1 seems to be working on mine. How does this have anything to do with my answer?

Comment: If you are using 9.1, it might not be the original iPad. If that's the case, the latest iOS is 9.3.2. So you are bound to get an update notification. You could choose to ignore it. There is no way to turn it off.

Comment: It says Model: MC764LL/A Version: 9.1 (13B143)

Comment: That is the iPad 2. iPad 2 and above supper iOS 9. Hence the latest iOS is 9.3.2.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, your iPad (MC764LL/A) is an iPad 2, and not the original iPad as mentioned. 
The latest version of iOS on your iPad is iOS 9.3.2. Since you are using iOS 9.1, you will get an update notification. You could, however, choose to ignore it. 
I would suggest you install the new OS. 
To answer your question: No, you cannot turn off the notification for an iOS software update.